# Why can't I format these numbers? JS

Tags: javascript, laravel

Why is this format method not working?

```
formatNum(value) {
    return value.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 0});
},
```

I'm using it like this

```
<el-table-column
    label="Horas">
    <template slot-scope="scope">
        {{formatNum(scope.row.hours)}}
    </template>
</el-table-column>
```

It's just not doing anything but if I try this it works?

```
 {{formatNum(2.000)}}
```

This is the current out put `2.000` I want `2`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you're using some type of framework. Might be a good idea to specify exactly what that is. Seems like your functions works, but the framework portion isn't working as intended. I would try to either put a `console.log` in your `formatNum` function or maybe just render the raw value of `scope.row.hours` to see if it's the value you're expecting.

Comment: @mwilson it's tagged as laravel, and i'm using vue/element-ui but I've used this exact function in another project with the same setup before without issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `{{scope.row.hours}}` is a string

This is the new method

```
formatNum(value) {
    value = parseInt(value, 10);
    return value.toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumFractionDigits: 0});
},
```